# Windows Forms message box doesn't work in published ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, dll, messagebox

We're developing .Net Application using asp.net and C# and .Net Framework 3.5.

We are using windows form message box in a .Net application.
This windows form works great on the debug mode but once we publish the application this message box won’t work.
We are referencing  System.Windows.Form.dll in order to use the message box features.
Kindly advice if we need to register this DLL or follow some configuration steps in order to solve this problem.

Thank in advanced,
Jad

Comment: Are you developing WinForms or WPF application? Which Framework?

Comment: No i'm developing .Net Application using asp.net and C# and .Net Framework 3.5

Answer (score 5):

*Don't* use MessageBox in a web application.  It will show up on the server console, there's nobody around to click the OK button.  I assume that ASP.NET has some counter-measures against it, given that it is such a serious denial-of-service attack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unreferenced classes a project/solution is usually not even compiled. 
So probably the problem is in another place. Are you sure that the code that should display the MessageBox is executed?

**EDIT:** When you develop web applications (ASP.NET), as described by you in comments, you cannot use Winforms MessageBox.

Try showing it with javascript, if you really need it

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('This a message')</script>");
```

Comment: I have added a project to my application.this project creates the message box.then i have referenced this project into my WebApplication. the message box displays on the debug mode but not on the published mode. i dont know why. maby System.Windows.Form.dll must be registered.

Comment: @Jad M: I assume the reason why the message box displays in debug mode but not in release mode can be found in Hans Passant's answer. The release mode more than likely prevents you from showing a message box on the server console where there's no one around to read it, or worse, no one around to click the OK button. You do not ever have to register .NET assembly libraries (like System.Windows.Forms) yourself.